# HTML table browser render issues

Tags: html, html-table

a. Consider this markup:

```
<table><th></th></table>
```

When i inspect the page i get:

```
<body><table><tbody><tr><th></th></tr></tbody></table>
```

b. Consider this markup:

```
<table><span role="columnheader"></span></table>
```

When i inspect the page i get:

```
<body><span role="columnheader"></span><table></table>
```

- Tested on chrome, ff and explorer (11).

How can it be?

I ran this situation while i tried to test the `parentNode` and didn't got "table" on both scenarios as expected.

Can someone please shade light on this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sets of HTML are invalid and the browser is performing error recovery. The recovery rules (or rather, the [general parser rules](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-intable)) for a span inside a table element are different to the recovery rules for a th inside a table element.

(To oversimplify, a th element has to be inside a tr inside a tbody/tfoot/thead inside a table … so the missing elements are added, but a span doesn't have to be inside a table at all so is thrown out).

You should just write valid HTML from the outset.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will look at it deeply. Does it means that the aria-role shouldn't get complex with semantically elements - so if `table` is the parent i can't use other element (ie span or div - even if i specify the matching role)?

Comment: A `<span>` can be a child of `<th>`, `<td>`, or `<caption>`, not `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`, `<colgroup>`, `<col>`, or `<tr>` -regardless of your aria attributes.

Comment: Yes, `aria-role` doesn't change the parsing rules for HTML (

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments. According to downvotes i guess this is a basic that any developer should know... Than again i'm writing tests functions to run on different pages to check if it correctly render, and this table topic got me spending couple of hours of my life... (: