# How to add a div below a row of table which is collapsable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a kind of a lobby. The lobby will contain a list of games. Displayed in `<table>`. Each `<tr>` contains name, no of players etc in `<td>`. Now I want that when I click on the row a corresponding details of the game should be displayed.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>

<table class="table text-align=">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  
    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#game-1">
      <td>Game 1</td>
      <div class="collapse" id="game-1">Description of game 2</div>
    </tr>

    <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#game-2">
      <td>Game 2</td>
      <div class="collapse" id="game-2">Description of game 2</div>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried to use that `<div>` inside `<tr>`. But that didn't worked well and its showing details outside table.

- I want to make the details appear right after the row.
- My second question is that what is the best way to on show only one deatils at a time.

**Note:** I know I can add another row after the row but that will ruin the structure of my table. So I don't wanna do that.

Comment: Using a `div` as a sibling of a table row is invalid. You'll need to add another tablecell or tablerow to achieve what you want. Or you need to think about a whole other structure, for example with a list

Comment: you could use modal boxes if your designs permit

Comment: @LinkinTED The problem with list will be all the columns will not aligned

Comment: Move your `div` tags into the table `td` tags and it will work just fine. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/dwaL9yo0/)

Comment: For this table behevior you can check MY recently  downvoted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492850/html-table-browser-render-issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is simple implementation based on your code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.collapse-item').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const target = $(this).data('target');
        
        if (!$(target).hasClass('show')) {
            $('.collapse-content').removeClass('show');
        }
        
        $(target).toggleClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
.table .collapse-content > td {
    padding: 0 .75rem;
}
.collapse-content > td > div {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.table .collapse-content.show > td {
    padding: .75rem;
}
.collapse-content.show > td > div {
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.collapse-content > td, .collapse-content > td > div  {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.collapse-content.show > td, .collapse-content.show > td > div {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      
<button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>

<table class="table text-align">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="collapse-item" data-target="#game-1">
            <td>Game 1</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="collapse-content" id="game-1">
            <td>
                <div>Description of game 1</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="collapse-item" data-target="#game-2">
            <td>Game 2</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="collapse-content" id="game-2">
            <td>
                <div>Description of game 2</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternatively, you can use [Bootstrap accoridon](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example):

```css
#accordion {
    margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 
 <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Game #1
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                Game 1 details
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Game #2
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                Game 2 details
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You may also look at [Datatables child rows](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). And here is [sliding example](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-10-02).

Comment: Your first answer seems very close to my needs. Just fix one thing. The details box is not sliding it just immediately shows up.

Comment: If you want to animate a table row, that row should have a height larger than it's minimum height. Anyway, I edited the answer. Hope this helps you.