# REACTJS: how to make <th> print only once and align properly with <td>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have 2 loops in order to access the data. The problem is when I place my `<th>` outside Inner loop, `<th>` does not align with `<td>` and if I place my `<th>` inside inner for loop, `<th>` will repeat many times.

how can i make my table header `<th>` appear only once and align properly with the table data `<td>`?

here is the code: (I am using ReactJS)

```
<body>{item.table_text_data.map((c,j)=> (
     <div>
      <table>
         <tr><th>bottom</th><th>Height</th><th>Left</th><th>Right</th><th>Text</th></tr>
            {c.map((i,k) => { return (
              <p  key={'child' + k}>
             <tr><td>{i.bottom}</td>
              <td>{i.height}</td>
              <td>{i.right}</td>
              <td>{i.left}</td>
              <td>{i.text}</td></tr> 
           </p>
         )})}
       </table>
    </div>))} 
</body>
```

And the output I'm getting for this is:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjNAp.png

So as you can see in the above screenshot, `<th>` is not aligned with `<td>`.

how can i overcome this? any help is much appreciated. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow the [documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html) about correct table formatting (for example `p` is not a valid child of `tr` etc).

Try this:

```
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>bottom</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                    <th>Left</th>
                    <th>Right</th>
                    <th>Text</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
{item.table_text_data.map((c,j)=> ( {c.map((i,k) => { return (
                <tr key={'child' + k}>
                    <td>{i.bottom}</td>
                    <td>{i.height}</td>
                    <td>{i.right}</td>
                    <td>{i.left}</td>
                    <td>{i.text}</td>
                </tr> 
)})}))} 
           </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: @sanjaysrinivasa i learned that the hard way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58492850/html-table-browser-render-issues